# How do you make this vintage chrometype style?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

I see a lot of those on Instagram and I want to do an artwork in this style but it seems that this is a special shader or maybe even render engine? How is this made in Blender and Photoshop?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shader itself shouldn't be too complicated. Something like this should suffice:

[image: PurpShade]

The "sheen" of the material moves in relation to the camera and light source(s). The light in my scene comes from a mid grey world background and no direct light. The background appears purple, but I did that to match your photo (kinda) only - I removed its influence from the model or the reflections.

The rest of the "vintage" look seems to come from a depth of field blur (or composite blur), as well as some additional "noise" (can be done through compositing or even volumetrics between the camera and object(s).

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the Layer weight node doing? I always wondered!

Comment: Both the outputs of _layer weight_ are "Fresnel" based - that is to say they blend between 2 shaders with one shader appearing on angles that are closer to "straight ahead" (relative to camera) and the other being more prevalent around the very edges of rounded objects, where normals point perpendicular, and reflections tend to look more "compressed". Think of the _fresnel_ output as more of a logarithmic falloff (ie. pretty much no blend up to the very edge, where it ramps up quickly - more realistic) and _facing_ as having more of a linear falloff.